# "Most of the books are already written"

Tags: grammar-choice

What are some ways to say "Most of the books are already written" (and preferably avoid ambiguity with *many*)?

This question was triggered by this sentence from Seneca (*Moral Letters* 79):

> *Iam multum operis effecti est; immo, si verum fateri volo, non multum*. (Much of the work is done already, well...actually... maybe not that much)

But if the plural is used (i.e., *opera effecta*) instead of the singular, how should it be rendered, is it: "Iam multum operum effectorum **sunt**" or **est**? Also, is it correct to use *multum* in that way? should it be *multi* or *plurimi*? If we were to use any construction was this ambiguous with "many" rather than "much"? should we avoid the partitive genitive in that case?

One way to resolve the ambiguity is to use *magna pars* + genitive. In this case examples show we should use the singular. (c.f. *Maior pars **mortalium**, Pauline, de naturae malignitate **conqueritur***).

But, the intriguing part of Seneca's example is that the predicate(?) is inside the partitive genitive which one could also translate, in theory, as an adjectival addition without force that could be omitted ("There is already much of the done-work"; nota bene: not "much of the work is done" but "much of the done-work"), so not sure we should use *est* and not *sunt* in this case.